# Support higher version of android api

Tags: android

I want to launch NFC settings activity, which is done using action ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS prior to API level 16. But in API level 16 and above it is done using ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS.
I am compiling my source using Android 4.0.3 which is API level 15.
How can I support for higher level so that it can open NFC settings in all versions.
Do i need to compile my source with API level 16 or higher and make min sdk version 15?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would typically compile your application with the SDK of the highest API version that you use in your code (or the latest available SDK). In your app's manifest you add the minimum and target SDK versions:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="..." android:targetSdkVersion="..." />
```

These values define how your app will be treated on a device in terms of (backwards) compatibility features.

Then, in your code, whenever you use API calles that are not available on a certain API level, you would surround those calles with a check for the `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT` (as [JaKoZo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24549420/2425802) showed).

With regard to the NFC settings, you could do even without that check and instead catch the exception that is thrown when no activity is registered for the `ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS` intent:

```
try {
    this.startActivityForResult(
            new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS),
            1); // magic number to detect when this startActivityForResult returns
} catch (Exception e) {
    try {
        this.startActivityForResult(
                new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS),
                1); // magic number to detect when this startActivityForResult returns
    } catch (Exception e1) {
    }
}
```

Instead of the constant `ACTION_NFC_SETTINGS`, you could also use the hard-coded string  `"android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS"`. While I don't really recommend this, you would not need to build against a higher API level (if it's only that constant that causes you to do so).

```
[...]
    this.startActivityForResult(
            new Intent("android.settings.NFC_SETTINGS"),
            1); // magic number to detect when this startActivityForResult returns
[...]
```

Comment: yes this is the way i commented above, and that worked

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
//do stuff

}
```

u mean this?

Comment: Yes this was my initial thought, but I need to do write API level specific calls inside if-else, my source is using API level 15 in this case I can not use API 16 calls inside if-else. I think setting min-sdk 15 or 14 in menifest file and using android 4.4(API 19) to compile source will work. I will update if I am able to execute my scenario.